# How to reset input components on change of <p:selectOneMenu> after certain validations are violated

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm populating `<p:selectOneMenu>` from a database which contains a list of zones, when a JSF page loaded.

When a zone in this menu is selected, a set of `<p:inputText>` is displayed in which a user can insert charge that corresponds to product weight which is to be transferred by a transporter to the selected zone in the menu. This can be shown in the following [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4N5s.png).

[image]

As can be seen, when non numeric values are entered by a user, validation violations occurs, when the given save button `<p:commandButton>` is pressed (the numbers displayed on top of each text field correspond to weight).

If a user now change the zone in the menu - the first panel without pressing the reset button, the data corresponds to that **newly selected zone** is loaded in these text fields only when the reset button is pressed as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndtxu.png) (because of validation violation)..

[image]

So, how to load data after previous validation violation, if an item (zone) is changed in the menu?

The change event of `<p:selectOneMenu>`, in this case should do the function something like which is done by `<p:resetInput>`.

Hope you will be able to understand what I mean :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, you need the functionality provided by `<p:resetInput>` inside `<p:ajax>` of a `<p:selectOneMenu>`.

Imagine that you currently have a:

```xml
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="zone">
        <f:selectItems ... />
        <p:ajax listener="#{bean.changeZone}" update="data" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:panel id="data">
        ...
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Your solution depends on PrimeFaces version used.

### PrimeFaces 4.0+

Set the `resetValues` attribute of `<p:ajax>` to `true`. This will reset the values of components covered by `update` attribute.

```xml
<p:ajax listener="#{bean.changeZone}" update="data" resetValues="true" />
```

### PrimeFaces 3.4+

The `resetValues` was only introduced in 4.0. If you're still on 3.4+ and you cannot ugrade, then use `<p:resetInput>`. The only issue is that it requires being placed in a component implementing [`ActionSource`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/component/actionsource) such as `UICommand` components. Your best bet is to let `<p:remoteCommand>` take over the `<p:ajax>` change listener job. Therein you can put a `<p:resetInput>`.

Then this change should do:

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="zone" onchange="changeZone()">
        <f:selectItems ... />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:remoteCommand name="changeZone" process="@this zone" action="#{bean.changeZone}" update="data">
        <p:resetInput target="data" />
    </p:remoteCommand>  

    <p:panel id="data">
        ...
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Don't forget to remove the `AjaxBehaviorEvent` argument from the listener method. It's useless in this particular case anyway.

### OmniFaces

In case you've OmniFaces at hands, then you can also use its [`ResetInputAjaxActionListener`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/ResetInputAjaxActionListener). It was actually the inspiration behind the later introduced `<f|p:ajax resetValues>` and `<p:resetInput>`. The OmniFaces `ResetInputAjaxActionListener` can be activated in multiple ways, even application-wide as a phase listener:

```xml
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

This will automatically reset values of all components specified in `update` attribute which are **not** covered by `execute` attribute.

Comment: I have just given it a try. It worked just fine. Thank you very much :)

Comment: PrimeFaces introduced an attribute called `<p:ajax ... resetValues="true" />` some time ago that you can nestedly use with `<p:selectOneMenu>`.