# Reset selectoneMenu with another selectOneMenu without ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I want to reset a selectOneMenu with another selectOneMenu to the default value and I can't use ajax.
First menu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.rel}" id="relSelection" 
                       valueChangeListener="#{bean.onRelChange}" onchange="submit();"
                       immediate="true">
                       <f:selectItems value="#{bean.rel}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Menu I want to reset:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.domSelected}" id="domSelection"
                 valueChangeListener="#{bean.onDomChange}" onchange="submit()"
                 hideNoSelectionOption="true" immediate="true" >
                 <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select..."
                 noSelectionOption="true" />
                 <f:selectItems value="#{bean.domNames}" var="item"
                 itemLabel="#{item}" itemValue="#{item}"/>                                    
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

If the first menu is selected after the second already was selected by the user I want to reset the second menu.

I expected that the second menu would display the noSelectionOption after I set its value to null from the onReleaseChange listener, but it keeps the selected value.
Listener:

```
public void onRelChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
  domSelected = null; //type String
  rel = (String) event.getNewValue();
 //som other stuff

}
```

I already tried the remoteCommand approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169208/how-to-reset-input-components-on-change-of-pselectonemenu-after-certain-valid)
by adding this:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="resetInputs" process="@this relSelection" 
                 actionListener="#{bean.clearMenu}" immediate="true">
    <p:resetInput target="domSelection" />
</p:remoteCommand>
```

In the first menu I called the remoteCommand via onChange="submit(); resetInputs()"

Any other Ideas or Ideas why this is not working?

Thanks!

Primefaces 6.1

JSF 2.2

GlassFish 4.1.1

Comment: Hint: remoteCommand **IS** ajax...

Comment: thanks for that, I wasn't aware of that and I'm only starting with JSF and Primefaces. 
It's not that I can't use ajax. I don't, cause I noticed that some primefaces components don't work anymore after I update them through ajax.